Deriving the multivariate asset returns model and interpreting cholesky factorization
I am trying to understand the multivariate asset returns model for a portfolio of assets from chapter 4 DCC-GARCH of Orskaug "Multivariate DCC-GARCH Model With Various Error Distributions" (2009) on page 15.
I want to try to get an intuitive understanding so I tried to derive the multivariate asset returns model as shown below:
My understanding is that in a portfolio of assets a single asset's return can be decomposed into the asset's univariate mean component and the square root of the covariances of all the other assets in the portfolio multiplied to a stochastic component $Z_t$.
To keep it simple let's say mean component is zero for all the assets.
The idea is that the deviation (from the zero mean) is not only affected by the standard deviation of the asset concerned but also due to correlations with all the other assets in the portfolio.
Basically, other assets in the portofolio influence the deviation in the returns of the asset concerned. Does this imply that the correlation between two asset returns is the conditional correlation? I do NOT mean time-varying correlation here but the correlation between the two asset returns while controlling for all the other assets.
We would just want the covariance of an asset to another asset alone so that summing these covariances for all the assets and the concerned asset's variance makes sense.
What I mean is as follows:
Porfolio of 3 asset returns: $x_1, x_2,x_3$
To model the returns of $x_1$ at a time instant, t:
$x_1 = \mu_1 + [ \sqrt{var(x_1|x_2,x_3)},  \sqrt{Cov(x_1,x_2 | x_3)}, \sqrt{Cov(x_1,x_3 | x_2)} ]^T \ [z_1, z_2, z_3] \\  $
$x_2 = \mu_2 + [   \sqrt{Cov(x_2,x_1 | x_3)}, \sqrt{var(x_2|x_1,x_3)}, \sqrt{Cov(x_2,x_3 | x_1)} ]^T \ [z_1, z_2, z_3] \\  $
$x_3 = \mu_3 + [  \sqrt{Cov(x_3,x_1 | x_2)}, \sqrt{Cov(x_3,x_2 | x_1)} , \sqrt{var(x_3|x_1,x_2)}]^T \ [z_1, z_2, z_3] \\  $
where $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3 = 0$ and $[z_1, z_2, z_3]$ is the stochastic component vector
This can be compactly represented as the matrix equation below
$ X = M + {COV^{1/2}}Z$
where the square root is the Hadamard root of the conditonal covaraiance matrix, $COV$.
Is this formulation correct? Can you please suggest what is wrong here and why do they use choleskly factorization of the covariance matrix instead?
The lower triangular matrix means that for asset 1 we do not consider the other assets in the multiplication due to zeros in first row of the cholesky factorization, and for asset 2 we do not consider other than first 2 assets in the multiplication due to zeros in second row of the cholesky factorization. This can be said about all the remaining rows of the cholesky factorization. Does this show that we are only capturing all the inter-asset dependencies for the last asset alone?
How can I intuitively understand the cholesky factorization in chapter 4 DCC-GARCH on page 15 as I have tried to do in my derivation?
EDIT: Is Cholesky decomposition typically performed on the unconditional covariance matrix, which represents the covariance structure of the variables without conditioning on any specific values?
Unconditional covariance matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix} var(x_1) &  Cov(x_1,x_2) & Cov(x_1,x_3) \\ cov(x_2,x_1) &  var(x_2) & Cov(x_2,x_3) \\ cov(x_3,x_1) &  Cov(x_3,x_2) & var(x_3) \end{bmatrix}$
As 2 asset example, if $
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\ \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2 \end{pmatrix}$
The cholesky decomposition is:
$L = \begin{pmatrix} l_{11} & 0 \\ l_{21} & l_{22} \end{pmatrix}$
$l_{11}^2 = {\sigma_1^2}$
$l_{22}^2 = \sigma_2^2 - \frac{{\rho^2 \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2}}{{l_{11}^2}}$
$l_{21} = \frac{{\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2}}{{l_{11}}}$
What is the meaning of terms $l^2_{22} =  \sigma_2^2 - \rho^2 \sigma_2^2$ and $l_{21} = {\rho\sigma_2}$ ? Why is it subtracted away
